# Access Visual child Elements from viewmodel wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I have a view as follows.. I want to access all the check boxes in the listview of the Main window in the viewmodel..But in the context of the main window it works fine..But in the view model if I say `IEnumerable<CheckBox> all = window.allboxes();`its not working..Please help..

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{


    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        EntityViewModel ev = new EntityViewModel();
        this.DataContext = ev;


    }

    public IEnumerable<CheckBox> allboxes()
    {
        IEnumerable<CheckBox> myboxes = FindVisualChildren<CheckBox>(this);
        return myboxes;
    }


    public static IEnumerable<T> FindVisualChildren<T>(DependencyObject depObj) where T : DependencyObject
    {
        if (depObj != null)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(depObj); i++)
            {
                DependencyObject child = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(depObj, i);
                if (child != null && child is T)
                {
                    yield return (T)child;
                }

                foreach (T childOfChild in FindVisualChildren<T>(child))
                {
                    yield return childOfChild;
                }
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: The fact that you are trying to do this tells me you are doing it wrong. What problem are you actually trying to solve? A proper MVVM setup will not need this kind of code.

Comment: Actually I want to get reference to all the checked checkboxes in the list view so that in the viewmodel I could retrieve the appropriate ids from the observable collection and store them to the database..In short get the ids of all the checked checkboxes..Please help..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer, *don't do this*. The ViewModel should not be tightly coupled to the View, which knowing about a function/collection would certainly do.

**Long answer:**

Your data should be wrapped up in a "Selectable" version that includes a boolean to indicate that it is selected. Then, you can create an `ItemsControl` with a `CheckBox` in the item template bound to this field.

```
public class Selectable<T>
{
    public bool Selected {get; set;}
    public T Data {get; set;}
}
```

Now, when you need to get all the selected items, you just write:

```
MyItems.Where(i => i.Selected);
```

To get the IDs:

```
MyItems.Where(i => i.Selected).Select(i => i.Data.ID);
```

Your view represents the data in the view model, you should *never* have to do direct manipulation of the UI from the View Model.

Comment: Basically I have a model as Entity Framework and view model that has the id, name properties in a collection and that collection binded to the list view control with custom check boxes for every row. Now if a checkbox is checked how do I get the respective id of that checkbox..Please help..I tried plugging in the above code but Collection.Where(i=>i.Selected) Selected property is not accessible.

Comment: @nikhil Instead of holding the EF DTO in your collection, you need to wrap it in a `Selectable` class similar to the one I posted. Does that makes sense?

Comment: Yea sure Bradley thank you very much for your help. Actually I changed my stored procedure structure and added a ischecked column..And im associating that procedure with the table I actually need to insert data when the check box is checked.. Its working right now..Thank you very much for your help Bradely..

Comment: @nikhil I'm glad you got it working. `IsChecked` is not something you would typically store in a database, hence my suggestion for a wrapper class. Glad you got it working though!

Comment: Thanks Brandly for the suggestion.. I will keep this in mind when working further..